# Convert mm/dd/yyyy to ww/yyyy in Excel?

Tags: excel, date

I have a date: `9/21/2015`. I want to convert this date into the format `39/2015`. If the date is in A2, I can easily do this with `CONCATENATE(WEEKNUM(A2), "/", TEXT(A2, "yyyy"))`. However, I can't seem to make Excel realize that these numbers should be ordered. When I go to make a pivot table, the ordering is completely lost. How can I make this work? Do I have to use some sort of serial number (perhaps the serial number for the Monday of each week)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula converts the dates to text and when sorting text, excel looks at the first character then the second and so on.  So 2/2015 will come after 19/2015.

To fix that you need to put a two digit week number.  Use:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(WEEKNUM(A1),"00"), "/", TEXT(A1, "yyyy"))
```

This will put a `0` in front of the first 9 weeks so the get sorted to the top correctly.

Comment: How can I get that to work with a pivot chart, though? I still lose the order when I go to make a line graph of my data. I'm plotting a time series and `12/2016` is right next to `11/2015`, when I have lots of data between those two dates.

Comment: Edit: I figured it out. I just took the first Monday of each week to generalize the date axis of my time series.